# PowerMockito.whenNew not working on android's Intent class

Tags: android, android-intent, powermock, powermockito

I am trying to use a mock Intent object but when using whenNew from PowerMockito, I am not able to mock the constructor. I have tried all possible combination of Arguments, but it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem, and solution was found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317804/using-powermockito-whennew-is-not-getting-mocked-and-original-method-is-called).

To be more specific: please try to add `@PrepareForTest` annotation at  test or at class level, and provide it with **class that constructs your Intent**.

```
public class SomeClassThatCreatesIntent {

    public void someMethodWithIntent() {
        Intent i = new Intent();
    }
}
```

And then test class should look like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SomeClassThatCreatesIntent.class})
public class SomeClassThatCreatesIntentTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // Some test that uses PowerMockito.whenNew(Intent.class)
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.