# Powermockito: mock a constructor

Tags: java, junit, mockito, webservice-client, powermockito

I have a Service class(MyService) that instantiates a WebserviceClient class(WSService_Service) using constructor.

I tried mocking it using

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(WSService_Service.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(wSService);
```

But it wont work, It would still go through the WSService_Service class constructor which calls a super method of a WebserviceClient.

How do I mock the constructor in methodToTest() method below?

```
 @Service
    public class MyService {

    public void methodToTest(){
        WSService  wsService_Service = new WSService_Service().getWSServicePort();
        SomeObjectResponose = wsService_Service.someService(); // I want to verify if this method is called.
    }

}


import javax.xml.ws.Service;

@WebServiceClient(name = "WSService", .....//some code ommitted)
public class WSService_Service extends Service{

   static {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://url.ommited");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
           //code ommitted
        }
        WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }

    public WSService() {
        super(WSDL_LOCATION, SERVICE);
    }

    public WSService(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature ... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, SERVICE, features);
    }

    public WSService getWSServicePort() {
        return super.getPort(WSServicePort, WSService.class);
    }

    //some codes ommited..
}
```

Comment: You need `@RunWith` and `@PrepareForTest` annotations in your test case. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317804/using-powermockito-whennew-is-not-getting-mocked-and-original-method-is-called

Comment: Add the code for the Test class as well along with current `@Runwith` annotations

Comment: @gcharmae You're welcome