# Mocking creation of object inside other class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I'm trying to test methods inside my controller and one of the classes have creation of the object inside it like this:

```
  NewPaymentModel pModel = new NewPaymentModel();
```

Then I have if statement:

```
  if (pModel.getErrors().isEmpty()) {
```

This is exactly what I want to mock. My code is below:

```
Pr4Error error = Mockito.mock(Pr4Error.class);
List<Pr4Error> listOfErrors = new ArrayList<>();
listOfErrors.add(error);

final NewPaymentModel pModel = 
  PowerMockito.mock(NewPaymentModel.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);

PowerMockito.whenNew(NewPaymentModel.class).withNoArguments().
  thenReturn(pModel);      

Mockito.doReturn(pModel).when(facade).addNewPayment(pModel);
when(pModel.getErrors().isEmpty()).thenReturn(true);
```

**EDIT**.
What I got when run unit tests is nullpointerexception on last line of code.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer has already been given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317804/using-powermockito-whennew-is-not-getting-mocked-and-original-method-is-called). Basically there are various *pre-requisites* that your code has to conform to; for example you need to use the @PrepareForTest annotation (so that the *power* magic can kick in to **manipulate** byte code of your production classes).

The real answer is: when you are writing your **own** code, then simply write **easy to test code**. Start [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79). Meaning: instead of calling `new` within your production code, you could for example dependency-inject a factory for such objects. And that factory can be mocked the "normal" way. And your need to mock `new` vanishes; you can get rid of PowerMock(ito) ... and end up with **better** designed production code!

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I cannot change the code now. I understand idea of factory and dependency injection through the constructor. Also, I have @PrepareForTest annotation... Still, doesn't work.

Comment: Well, then that very first link should most likely do the job. Mocking new is well documented, and it works well - when you follow the documentation exactly. If you think you are; and it is still not working, we need a [mcve]. Your input is not sufficient; as it is **not** showing how you use that very annotation for example.