# Some hard mock problems in java 1.4, junit 3.8.1 and jmock 1.2

Tags: java, mocking, powermockito, legacy-code

I have such problem, as topikstarter here - [Using PowerMockito.whenNew() is not getting mocked and original method is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317804/using-powermockito-whennew-is-not-getting-mocked-and-original-method-is-called)

But I have java 1.4, junit 3.8.1 and jmock 1.2 - and no annotations, of course.

Problem is as it seems in this link - I have a method, which makes new Example(), and then calls Example.someMethod(); I need to get exception from this method to test it. In more wide terms, I need to know how to PowerMockito(or use any other framework) objects in java 1.4 - with junit 3 and without annotations. Make fake object, make any method take this mock object in "new", not create one, and mock it's methods. There is no even method PowerMockito.whenNew() in PowerMockito for junit3...

Any docs, "getting started"s and other things would help - I haven't found anything about PowerMockito for junit3, except of maven dependency link.

```
public class Example(){
             ExampleHelper helper = new ExampleHelper(5);
             public void doSmth(){ 
    try{
    int i = returnPlus(); 
    System.Out.Println("Nope, we shouldn't come here. We need to visit Catch block"); 
    } catch (myException e){ 
    System.Out.Println("Hoooray, exception!"); 
    }
}

    //different package 
public class ExampleHelper{
    int i;
    public ExampleHelper(int i){
    this.i = i;
    }    
    public int returnPlus() throws myException{//Yes, method signature tells us, that we are THROWING ecxeption
         return i+1;//yes, method DO NOT throws exception
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do something like this, but it doesn't work. In PowerMockito for junit3 there is no such methods - and if I trying to do this with PowerMock+Mockito - there should be annotations, and I have java 4 with no annotations aboard...

```
 public class TestHarderExample extends TestCase {
public void testSomething() {

    ExampleHelper exampleHelper = PowerMockito.mock(com.sources.ExampleHelper.class);
    Example example = new Example();

    try {
        PowerMockito.whenNew(ExampleHelper.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(exampleHelper);
        PowerMockito.when(exampleHelper.giveAplus()).thenThrow(new IOException("Dummy one"));
        Example.doSmth();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Good one!");
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Bad one...");
    }
```