# Mock New Object

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am trying to pass my responseEntityMock for this following snippet using, But it is not working.

```
ResponseEntity<byte[]> response =
          new RestTemplate().exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, byte[].class);
```

Can anyone tell me how to pass my own ResponseEntityMock for this code. Thanks.

I am using the following code:

```
   ResponseEntity<byte[]> responseEntity = PowerMockito.mock(ResponseEntity.class);
    RestTemplate restTemplateMock = PowerMockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(RestTemplate.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(restTemplateMock);
    when(restTemplateMock.exchange(eq(path), eq(POST), any(),
            eq(byte[].class))).thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

Comment: What are you trying, please post your code and the error you are getting. Also, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317804/using-powermockito-whennew-is-not-getting-mocked-and-original-method-is-called.

Comment: @Lazycoder_007 I have looked into the link you shared earlier but I couldn't find the relevant solution there. Thanks.

Comment: "But it is not working." ..What is not working. Can you post the error

Comment: While debugging i am getting this "handleInvocationTargetException(testMethod, e)"

Comment: Please include the exception stacktrace in the question.

Comment: @vsfDawg Actually there is No exception coming... It is just not able to take my mock... It is creating the object with null value.

Comment: @ANMOLJAIN can you post the full code of acutal method and test method